# Ubuntu installation stuck on first step!

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my [GL552-vw ASUS laptop](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ROG-GL752VW/) from a USB flash. But At the first step after hitting *Install Ubuntu* I stuck in the loading page:
[image]

This is what happened under the hood:
[image]

What's wrong?

What I have done so far:

1. I checked the checksum of my .ISO file and it is OK.
2. I tried both Ubuntu 16.10 and Ubuntu 16.04.1.
3. I disabled Windows 10 (Current OS on my Laptop) *Fast boot* option.

Note I'm trying to replace Windows 10 installed on my 128 G SSD with Ubuntu.

Comment: Looking at the error message at the bottom I would say that you have either a memory problem or a problem with a device plugged into a pcie port possibly the ssd

Comment: How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: I will do some research and see if I can find out

Comment: I Have found the device that appears to be causiing the error see the link for details https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086/a112    the best thing that i can think of is selecting try ubuntu and boot into a live session if it boots then try and install.

Comment: @Alex2012 Thank you dear Alex. Trying _try live Ubuntu_ fails too.

Comment: The msft0101 is a tpm module try disabling the tpm in the bios and then give my other suggestion another go

Comment: @Alex2012 No way to disable msft0101 or any other tpm module in my bios settings

Comment: @Abraham   Yes, way. All BIOS/UEFI have a setting to disable TPM.